# Failed to get adapter: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I get this error while I preview my app in IBM mobile first platform.

I have created an app using Hybrid Mobile (cordova) Application Project and I've imported javascriptSOAP (Sample adapter) adapter using Existing Maven Project.

I have used the following js code in index.js to integrate app and adapter

```
function validate() {   
    var params = {
        "GetCurrencyByCountry": { "CountryName": "INDIA" }
    };

    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'JavaScriptSOAP',
        procedure : 'GetCurrencyByCountry',
        parameters : [params]
    };

    //{"process":{"username":"$('#username').val()","userpwd":"$('#userpwd').val()"}}

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : loadFeedsSuccess,
        onFailure : loadFeedsFailure
    });
}

function loadFeedsSuccess(result){
    alert("in function");   
}   

function loadFeedsFailure(){
   alert("in error");
}
```

Adapter.xml file

```
<displayName>JavaScriptSOAP</displayName>
<description>JavaScriptSOAP</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>www.webservicex.net</domain>
        <port>80</port>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="GetCurrencyByCountry"/>
```

Error Message

{ [getAdapterError: failed to get adapter: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080]
  jse_shortmsg: 'failed to get adapter',
  jse_summary: 'failed to get adapter: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080',
  jse_cause: 
   { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080]
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 9080 },
  message: 'failed to get adapter: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080',
  name: 'getAdapterError' }
mfpdev-cli verb adapter Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080
mfpdev-cli verb adapter     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
mfpdev-cli verb adapter     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
mfpdev-cli verb adapter     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
mfpdev-cli verb adapter  form error:  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9080]
mfpdev-cli verb adapter   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
mfpdev-cli verb adapter   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
mfpdev-cli verb adapter   syscall: 'connect',
mfpdev-cli verb adapter   address: '127.0.0.1',
mfpdev-cli verb adapter   port: 9080 }

Please assist in integrating mobile project and adapter

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: This code snippet is of no value. Provide your adapter's XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide any useful information in the question (other than the title...). Until you provide actual information, like your adapter's XML file and the actual full error message from the server or client, what can be surmised is that you are not connecting to the correct IP address. 127.0.0.1 is not a valid IP address to use for the adapter to connect to.

Update your adapter's XML to the public IP address of the machine your MobileFirst Server is running on, re-build and re-deploy the adapter to the server.